# What is the best way to seperate one javascript file from the minified script?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

I'm not sure if this is the best way to articulate my question.

I have a script that I want to run on one page on the site.
All of the .js files are included/imported into an app.js file which is then minified and included in the layout.html which is used on every page.
There is one javascript file I want to use only on 1 of those pages(The pages that I don't need it on creates an error in the console so I can't just leave it). What is the best way to include it. Can I still include it with the minified script but only on that page?

Comment: How does the app.js file include scripts in the layout.html, why don't you just use script tags there?

Comment: You could probably change the code so it runs only on that page (for example, if an ID exists on that page)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have three options:

1. Include the script in the minified `app.js`, but modify it so it checks whether it's needed (e.g., check that the things it needs to work on are present rather than assuming they're there) before running. That way, `app.js` is the same on all pages, can be held in cache, your build script is straightforward, etc.
2. Have `app.js`, which doesn't include the script, and a separate minified version of the script that you only include on the desired page, using a separate `script` tag. Your build script is still fairly simple, and it only adds a single HTTP request to the target page.
3. Have two minified `app.js` files, `app.js` and `app-plus.js` (or whatever). Include `app.js` on all other pages, but include `app-plus.js` on the target page. This complicates `layout.html` because it has to determine which script to include, and complicates your build script (very slightly).

Unless the page-specific script is massive, option #1 is likely to be your best bet because of the simplicity (an extra few kilobytes once the HTTP connection is established aren't usually a big deal), but it really depends on your situation. If you need to support fairly low-bandwidth consumers (mobiles on high-rate data packages), that might argue against always including the script. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and listing the benefits of each option! For the first option, would you be able to send me in the right direction as to how to check and also prevent a part of the minified script from running if the page doesn't need it?

Comment: @Jessica - That depends entirely on what the script does. It's really down to you to figure out what it does and thus what it needs to check for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building regular HTML + CSS + JS page, then you can just add this javascript file (or more if you want) to a separate folder and then call it in the HTML file you want.

EG - this is your structure

```
-index.html
-about.html
-js-for-minify/do.js
-js/not.js
-dist/minified.js
-css
```

you can reference the about.html to have a script tag which is directed of the unminified file.

```
<script src="js/not.js">
```

while for the index.html you can reference the minified file

```
<script src ="dist/minified.js">
```